# Web Audio API Latency in Phonegap Project

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, web-audio-api

So I am using the Web Audio API for PhoneGap project. It plays multiple sounds (amount decided by the user) simultaneously. The below code works very well on android. There is minimal lag; however, on iOS there is quite a bit of lag especially once amount gets to six or so. How would I be able to minimize this? I have tried using the PhoneGap Media API, but then there was a horrible amount of lag on Android.

```
var myAudio = [];

for (i = 0; i < amount; i++) { //I have taken out some code to make it more simple
  myAudio[i] = new Audio(rand.path + ".mp3"); //rand is initialized before

}

for (i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
  myAudio[i].play();
}
```

Comment: How are you defining lag? The time in between the starting of individual sounds? Or the time in between pressing some button and playing some sounds.

Comment: @notthetup Sorry about being unclear. The lag is apparent when playing the individual sounds through the loop.